# Golang Gokogiri recursive xpath anomaly

Tags: xml, xpath, recursion, go

I was trying to perform xpath operations on a html document. I wanted to do a two-level xpath query. The html document "index.html" is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="head">
        <div class="area">
            <div class="value">10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="area">
            <div class="value">20</div>
        </div>
        <div class="area">
            <div class="value">30</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to get all divs with class="area" first, then recursively get divs inside it with class="value" in golang using Gokogiri.

My go code is as follows:
    package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/xpath"
)

func main() {
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("index.html")

    doc, _ := gokogiri.ParseHtml(content)
    defer doc.Free()

    xps := xpath.Compile("//div[@class='head']/div[@class='area']")
    xpw := xpath.Compile("//div[@class='value']")
    ss, _ := doc.Root().Search(xps)
    for _, s := range ss {
        ww, _ := s.Search(xpw)
        for _, w := range ww {
            fmt.Println(w.InnerHtml())
        }
    }
}
```

However, the output I get is odd:

```
10
20
30
10
20
30
10
20
30
```

I intend to get:

```
10
20
30
```

I want to recursively search for xpath patterns. I think there is something wrong with my second level xpath pattern. It appears, my second level xpath is again search in the whole document instead of individual divs with class="area". What do I do for recursive xpath patterns search? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An XPath search from any node can still search the entire tree.

If you want to search just the subtree, you can start the expression with a `.` (assuming you still want descendant-or-self), otherwise use a exact path.

```
xps := xpath.Compile("//div[@class='head']/div[@class='area']")
xpw := xpath.Compile(".//div[@class='value']")

// this works in your example case
// xpw := xpath.Compile("div[@class='value']")
// as does this
// xpw := xpath.Compile("./div[@class='value']")

ss, _ := doc.Root().Search(xps)
for _, s := range ss {
    ww, _ := s.Search(xpw)
    for _, w := range ww {
        fmt.Println(w.InnerHtml())
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
10
20
30
```

Comment: Yeah this solves my problem. What's the use of 'dot' there? That 'dot', does it signify current node? But in the for loop, if `s` is in context then `//div[@class='value']` also makes sense, right? I'm just saying because if the root element in each iteration is `div.area` then `//div[@class='value']` makes sense.

Comment: @ArunL: `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so on it's own the first slash indicated the tree root. The `.` is an alias for `self::node()` [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). (I'm sure there's a much better reference out there than wikipedia for this though)

Comment: also note the similarity to any file system where `.` stands for the current directory

Answer (score 2):

Your second query, `//div[@class='value']`, will select divs anywhere in the document regardless of the parent element. Instead, try `div[@class='value']`.

Comment: Hi, thanks! That indeed solved the problem. Btw, that second xpath `//div[@class='value']`, was it not searching in the current context? What if the `div.value` was deep inside the DOM under `div.area` and I wanted to search for the `div.value`?

Comment: Just saw your question. For future reference... yes it was starting from the current context (the context node). But since the XPath expression starts with `//`, the context node makes no difference, except for determining which document the `//` is relative to. If you want the XPath expression to select only `div` elements that are **descendants of the context node**, use `.//div[...]` (note the dot on the front).